# Flying domestically with my drivers license -- full name vs abbreviation

Tags: usa, air-travel, domestic-travel

Will I have trouble flying domestic when I go by Jeff and license is Jeffrey?

Comment: People call me Jon. My license/passport say Jonathan. No problem.

Comment: What you "go by" is not the issue. What will the name on the plane ticket be? It's generally best for it to match your ID

Comment: Just be careful that no one calls you Jeff while you are checking in.

Comment: And then there are my friends who go by their middle names…

Answer (score 13):

> Will I have trouble flying domestic when I go by Jeff and license is Jeffrey?

This isn't likely to be a problem, but you can eliminate the chance altogether by giving your name as *Jeffrey* when you buy your tickets.